# Vba Excel con la condicion If

Tags: vba, condiciones

Tengo un problema con If para poner la condicion a la celda estoy utilizando If empty pero cuando la celda coloco numero 0 me marca como vacia mi condicion es si esta vacia pero esta tomando al cero como vacia aca les mando el codigo..estoy trabajando con plantillas en excel con la herramienta vba.

```
Sub Imprimir_caratula()

If Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("Z3").Value = 2 Then

If Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G52").Value = Empty Or _
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G53").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Completar gravamenes y subincripciones"
    Else
'
' Imprimir Macro

    Sheets("Caratula").Visible = True
    Sheets("Mercantil").Visible = False
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = False
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Visible = False
    Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Descripciones").Visible = False
    Range("q117") = Date
    Range("ab117") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=3, To:=3, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Sheets("Mercantil").Visible = True
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = True
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Visible = False
    Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Descripciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Caratula").Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=7, To:=25, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=5, To:=5, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=2, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = False
    Range("C4").Select

    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70:J72").UnMerge
    Worksheets("Terreno Construcciones").Range("B15").Copy
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70:J72").Merge
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70").HorizontalAlignment = xlJustify


    End If

    Else

    If Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Range("L23").Value = Empty Or _
    Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Range("L24").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Completar los datos en vivienda comercio"
    Else
If Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G52").Value = Empty Or _
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G53").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Completar gravamenes y subincripciones"
    Else

    ' Imprimir Macro
'
    Sheets("Caratula").Visible = True
    Sheets("Mercantil").Visible = False
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = False
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Visible = False
    Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Descripciones").Visible = False
    Range("q117") = Date
    Range("ab117") = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=3, To:=3, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Sheets("Mercantil").Visible = True
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = True
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Visible = False
    Sheets("Terreno Construcciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Descripciones").Visible = False
    Sheets("Caratula").Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=7, To:=25, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=5, To:=5, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=2, To:=2, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Sheets("Fotos").Visible = False
    Range("C4").Select

    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70:J72").UnMerge
    Worksheets("Terreno Construcciones").Range("B15").Copy
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70:J72").Merge
    Worksheets("Mercantil").Range("B70").HorizontalAlignment = xlJustify

    End If
    End If
End If



End Sub
```

aca esta el codigo es una macro de plantilla todo esta bien excepto ese error cuando corre deberia marcar si la celda esta vacia no imprime pero cuando coloco numero 0 en la celda marca como vacio como podria corregir ese error.

Comment: Prueba a poner  `If x = vbnullstring` el vbnullstring significa que la celda está vacía, con un cero te daría falso.

Answer (score 1):

Es mucho mejor usar la función IsEmpty:

> **[IsEmpty (función)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function)**

En tu código, por ejemplo, utilizas:

`If Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G52").Value = Empty`

Cuando lo correcto sería usar:

`If IsEmpty(Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G52"))= True Then...`

Modifica tu código en todos los puntos que sea necesario, y nos cuentas si has podido resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar comillas dobles sin espacio en medio ( "" ) en lugar de Empty

Algo como esto:

```
If Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G52").Value = "" Or _
    Sheets("Datos Generales").Range("G53").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Completar gravamenes y subincripciones"
Else
```